# React-anime to animate entire component

Tags: reactjs

This is how we should use react-anime according to their doc :

```
<Anime 
  duration={4000}
  direction="alternate"
  loop={true}
  translateX='10rem'>
<div className="blue"/>
<div className="green"/>
<div className="red"/>
</Anime>
```

But I want to animate an entire component like so :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Anime from 'react-anime';
import Body from './Body';
import '../../css/style.css'

class Player extends Component {

  render() {
     return (
     <Anime 
     duration={4000}
     direction="alternate"
     loop={true}
     translateX='10rem'>
       <Body />
       </Anime>
   );
 }

}

export default Player;
```

But it doesnt seems to work, the component wont modify his translateX. Can someone help?

Thanks